# average of bin range in pandas

Tags: pandas, mean, cut, bin

How do you find the average of bin range in pandas?
I have used qcut to create bins and saved them as a new column in my dataframe.
Now I want to find the average of each bin range and save it as a new column to the same dataframe.
any ideas?!

```
Time        Value      TimeBin  
26.315704     2    (26.29, 26.318]
52.6705      11    (52.669, 78.893]
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Timebin')['Value'].mean()`

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks for your answer, but maybe I explained it in a wrong way, I wan the average of bin range! for example, in the case of first row, the average of of 26.29 and 26.318 is 26.304

Comment: Kindly share the input data as a dictionary: `df.to_dict('records')`

Comment: IIUC, try this `df['TimeBin'].apply(lambda x: x.mid)`  Looking at [pd.Interval](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html) docs.

Answer (score 1):

You are are looking for the mid point of a [pd.Interval](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html), let's use the `mid` attribute.

```
df['TimeBin'].apply(lambda x: x.mid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sol =  df.groupby(pd.qcut(df['Timebin'], bins=bins)) 
print(sol)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm afraid it returns error (missing 1 required positional argument: 'q') . I have used a simple number earlier to define the bins (q=10). I'm not sure how "bins=bins" is helpful